# Python: can't delete unwanted commas in a text file

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a CSV file that contains an information about people:

```
name,age,height

Maria,25,172

George,45,180,

Peter,23,179,
```

The problem is that some strings contain an extra commas in the end, and some don't (this appears because this information was got from the internet using `urlopen` in the other Python script which processes the raw data).

I tried to write some code to fix this, but I couldn`t get a result. What I've written:

```
import re


data = open('file.csv').read()

new_data = re.sub('\W$', '', data)
print(new_data)
```

But this code substitutes only **the last** comma in the whole document. I tried to write a cycle, which counts all lines and then analyses each line, but maybe my coding skills are not great and I didn't reach a success. Please, tell me, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You could pretty easily get something working with ```str.endswith(',')```

Comment: If you are sure there is no space between the comma and the end of the line, you could simply do: `new_data = data.replace(',\n', '\n')`

Comment: If you are sure that empty fields are only present at the end you can use `[s for s in data.split(',') if len(s)]`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the whole file is handled as a string, and `$` matches only the end of the string.
You would better use `re.sub('\W\n', '\n', data)`

You can also do that without regexp: `new_data = data.replace(',\n', '\n')`, which is probably faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple enough you don't really need `regex` (and its *probably* faster to not use it)

Here's what I would do:

```
with open("file.csv", 'r') as f:
    newLines = [line[:-1] if line.endswith(",") else line for line in f.readlines()]
```

Then all you need to do is write it back to the file